# Powershell V2.0 error:Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to create a dictionary in Powershell. Here is the script, I'm working on,

```
    $environmentId = "Test"
    $Dictionary = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]"
    $xml = [xml] (Get-Content "deploy.config")     
    $xml.SelectNodes("descendant::configuration/environment[@id='$($environmentId)']/descendant::text()[normalize-space()]") | ? Value | % { 
     $Dictionary.Add($_.ParentNode.ToString(), $_.Value)  
    }
write-output $Dictionary
```

This script is working in Powershell Version 4.0. But currently we are using Version 2.0. When I run this script on 2.0 version, throwing following error,

```
Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "Value" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
At C:\Users\pwsp_kkumar\Desktop\dictionary.ps1:6 char:129
+     $xml.SelectNodes("descendant::configuration/environment[@id='$($environmentId)']/descendant::text()[normalize-spa
ce()]") | ? <<<<  Value | % {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
```

Can someone please suggest me the Powershell version 2.0 equivalent command, to fix the above error. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this part of the pipeline:

```
? Value
```

If you're trying to make sure that the Value property is not null, you could use

? {$_.Value}

That should work with no problem.  It also matches what you're adding later ($_.Value).

Comment: Excellent. This fixed my problem. Thank you so much.